# R Markdown to PDF and horizontal line

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

With R markdown I can create an horizontal line with

`---`

This worked perfectly in RStudio on windows with Miktek.
But I switch to Tinytex and installed Tex Live, and now `---` works on html output, but no on pdf output.

Rendering to pdf I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.96 ...enter}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{\linethickness}
                                                  \end{center} 

Error: Failed to compile GSVIIIPE.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See GSVIIIPE.log for more info.
Ejecución interrumpida
```

I haven´t found a solution to this. Could anyone tell me is there is any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58397380/8416610

Comment: I see. This is a pandoc bug, so the better option is to wait until version 2.8. I hope this does not take too long!. Thanks

Comment: Does anyone knows when RStudio will be shipped with Pandoc 2.8. Currently it uses version 2.7.2, but this has the previous bug, which has been corrected in the already distributed version 2.8:

Comment: Even the most recent RStudio preview ships with pandoc 2.3.1. However, RStudio will use a system installed pandoc if it is more recent. In my case it is using version 2.5, which is what Debian Testing has. `print(rmarkdown:::find_pandoc())` will tell you which version is used and where it comes from.

Comment: RStudio Version 1.2.5019 on Windows uses 2.7.2. print(rmarkdown:::find_pandoc())
$version
[1] ‘2.7.2’

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that the pandoc version is OS specific. Anyway, have you brought this issue to RStudio developer's  attention?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal rule in R Markdown / Bookdown causing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587918/horizontal-rule-in-r-markdown-bookdown-causing-errors)

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thanks a lot.